# Когда оборачиваю приложение в компонент <ClerkProvider> возникает ошибка

Tags: next.js

решил использовать clerk, для авторизации в моем приложении. Когда оборачиваю приложение в компонент  возникает такая ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, все тексты ошибки должны быть текстами, а во-вторых, текст ошибки нужен полный (и тоже текстом)